# Latching Comparator Problem

Tags: analog, power-electronics, comparator, spice

I am working on a latching comparator design for the purposes of overcurrent protection. This is built around an LMV331 open collector high speed comparator. VIN is sourced from a current sense amplifier (not shown), and COMP OUT is tied to an active low shutdown pin of a MOSFET gate driver (also not shown). The operation is when voltage VIN (minus D2 diode voltage) is greater than the threshold voltage formed by voltage divider R2/R3, COMP OUT is pulled and latched to ground, as D1 becomes forward biased and thus pulling the threshold voltage to ~0.7V. Voltage divider R5/R6 biases the negative comparator input to ~1.6V, keeping it above D1 voltage, ensuring latch even if VIN falls to 0V. This circuit operation has been verified in SPICE.

I have physically implemented the circuit on PCB, and the comparator operation itself is functional, however the latch behavior is not. Rather the circuit is behaving as if there is no latching implemented. The test condition is 5V volts applied to VIN for 0.1 seconds. I have checked, and re-checked the schematic, connections, component values and bias voltages and everything as is designed. Any idea as to why the physical implementation of this circuit is not latching?

[image]

Comment: Look at the waveforms at the (+) and (-) inputs of the comparator, and also on the output. Use a 4-channel oscilloscope for that. Make sure they match your assumptions :)

Comment: Pin 5 isn't connected on your schematic. I assume you have it connected in the real implementation?

Comment: Yes it is, I redrew the schematic to make it cleaner for the post. It is connected.

Comment: If comparator has open-collector output, D1 and R1 can be omitted. Next step could be addition of transistor which will rise inverse input of comp. to +5V. May also be that circuit has problems at powering on and starting capacitor should be added somewhere.

Comment: @Vladimir, D1 and R1 can't be removed, whether it's open collector or not. They let the circuit output its result: near-0 V or pulled to 5 V.

Comment: Agree. Are there really 1N1183 diodes? Their capacitance and reverse current could make circuit work in simulation.

Comment: My bad, the diode part numbers in this schem are meant to be ideal. The actual part is 1N4004, and that’s what was used in the SPICE sim too

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing on the oscilloscope per recommendation, it looks like there was a bunch of noise on the comparator inputs, and the no-latch condition is a result of transients. I solved the problem  with the addition of 0.1uf ceramic caps to ground on each input, and latches stably now. I believe the noise is the result of the 5V SMPS I am using so I will look into that. Thanks guys.